# How can I insert value in the cell with style using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I'm trying to insert a String in the cell using Poi.
The problem is that the excel file is not empty but some style already has been applied.
The border of the cell I want to put the value has styled like the pic below.

[image]

Eventhough there is not any value in cells, console tell me that range of the border is already written.
Also I considered using HSSFWorkbook instead of SXSSFWorkbook.
However it seems more efficient to use SXSSF because I have to handle millions of data in another sheet of the same file.

[image]

If I use the empty sheet, the code works well.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code.

```
    public SXSSFWorkbook selectCalculateResultExcelValue(SXSSFWorkbook wb, Map<String, Object> searchParam) {

      SXSSFSheet xSheet=null;
      xSheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
      String data = "JEJU";
      Row bodyRow=null;
      bodyRow=xSheet.createRow(5);
      Cell bodyCell = bodyRow.createCell(0);
      bodyCell.setCellValue(data);

    return wb;
}
```

Comment: You use `SXSSFSheet`. Meaning only a portion of rows is accessible at a time. Seems you are no longer in the accessible window. Also `HSSFWorkbook` is for the old .xls files. `XSSFWorkbook` is for the new .xlsx files. `SXSSFWorkbook` is simply a streamed version where only a portion of rows is accessible. In addition to that, if you already have data in the workbook, `SXSSFWorkbook` does not really have an advantage, if you have to access that specific data, as its only streamed writing, but not reading

Comment: TL;DR use `XSSFWorkbook` to manipulate existing workbooks. Use `SXSSFWorkbook` for creating completely new files

Comment: Don't call `createRow` or `createCell` - those will recreate existing cells and wipe stuff. If you already have styled cells, go `getRow` and `getCell`